# Waiting until a routine ends on Arduino

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, communication, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 6 with installed TComPort component and Arduino. Thing that I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
for (int a = 0; a < n; a++){
    Edit1->Text = "first";
    ComPort->WriteString("a");
    //wait till process on Arduino is finished
    //receive char from Arduino and continue
    Edit1->Text = "scnd";
    ComPort->WriteString("b");
    //wait till process on Arduino is finished
}
```

Arduino code (case):

```
case 'b':
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write('2');
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
    break;
```

I was trying to use OnRxChar but there is problem with receiving strings from Arduino. Sometimes they are "blank" and sometimes they are correct (2).
Can somebody guide me what is the best function that I can use ?

Edit:
ComPort has a function `Read(void *,int,bool)` but I have no idea what `void*` and `int` stands for (I'm newbie).

Edit 2: **Solution !!**
This is what I did:

> 1st function;
>   Timer1->Enabled=false;
>   {instructions};
>   ComPort->Write('a');
>
> 2nd function OnRxChar;
>   {instructions};
>   Timer1->Enabled=true;
>
> 3rd function Timer;
>   go back to 1st function

When I was using Sleep instead of Timer whole app freeze. I hope it will be usefull to someone :) I spend around week to figure it out :P

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ComPort->WriteString("b");` You're sending the character array `b\0`.
On the arduino side, it seems (as you don't show how you read the input and what is the switch condition), that you're reading a character.

So basically what you do is:

```
Ard                Host
 | <---['a','\0']--- |
 |                   |
 | ----['2']-------> |
 | <---['b','\0']--- |
```

There, your host is sending first `a`, matching the switch case condition, and at next read it will read `\0` matching none of the switch case conditions.

I don't know about `ComPort` arguments, but you should look at some method that would be like `ComPort->WriteChar(char)` instead of `ComPort->WriteString(string)`, so you'd exchange only characters:

```
Ard                Host
 | <---['a']-------- |
 |                   |
 | ----['2']-------> |
 | <---['b']-------- |
```

UPDATE (cf first comment):

As I found no public documentation of `ComPort`, I can't exactly help you there, but to make your C++ code wait for an input from the arduino, you shall do something that would look like what follows:

```
// blocks while there is no input on the serial line
while (!ComPort->available());
```

if you don't have the arduino-like method `available()` in comport, you can always do something like

```
char input = '\0';
while ((c = ComPort->ReadChar()) == ERROR);
```

where `ERROR` is the value returned on timeout, or if it does not you can check against `!= '2'`.

HTH

Comment: When I'm sending string to Arduino it switch on the led. My problem is how to wait till the Arduino process end and move to next line in c++.

Comment: I was trying to do it with while loop but it program freeze when it get inside loop :/ I found another solution: I use ComPort1->Read(buff,1,true); and program wait for char (that's great!) but I need to add ShowMessage for program to do lines under Read function, otherwise it just skip them :/

Comment: ok, that's the same idea, you block the input until there's something on the line.